# int in javascript returning as string in php

Tags: javascript, php, string, int

I am sending some data from ajax to a php script that passes it to an api. I noticed that the data being console.log'd from my javascript has ints where ints are required but when I altered my php to return the data back to my script so that I could make sure it is structured correctly, all of my ints come back as strings.

example:

javascript

```
[{"UnitID":563614,"InsuranceID":null}]
```

php

```
[{"UnitID":"563614","InsuranceID":"NaN"}]
```

I am confused as to why this is happening. How the javascript has it is how it should be, but php seams to want to convert all of the ints to strings when it receives the data.

Here is the relevant part of my scripts

javascript

```
function wssReserve(form) {

    var sendinsid   = parseInt(form.InsuranceID.value);

    data = {
        "Units": [{
            "InsuranceID": sendinsid
        }]
    };

    var settings2 = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "php.script",
        "data": { json: { data } },
        "method": "POST"
    };

    var a2 = $.ajax(settings2);

    $.when(a2).done(function(d2) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(d2));

    });

}
```

php

```
function wssLocationReserve($data) {

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $url = 'external.api';
    $auth = 'Authorization: Basic auth-token';

    //$post_data = json_encode($_POST['data'});

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            $auth,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
        ),
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_decode($data));
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$json = $_POST['json'];

if( strcasecmp($_GET['method'],'hello') == 0){
    $response['code'] = 1;
    $response['status'] = $api_response_code[ $response['code'] ]['HTTP Response'];
    $response['data'] =  wssLocationReserve($json);
}

deliver_response($_GET['format'], $response);
```

if I return the $result instead of $data I get this from the api

```
 {\"Success\":false,\"ErrorMessage\":\"An unhandled exception has occurred and been logged.\"}
```

Comment: perhaps `deliver_response` messes with the data? perhaps the external API is sending you exactly what you are sending from PHP? have you debugged the PHP to see what it is receiving? have you checked `deliver_response` to see it's not messing with the data? Didn't you ask this question about an hour ago?

Comment: @adeneo I don't see what your talking about.

Comment: In php, where is $json defined?

Comment: @jan.vogt I added it. I accidentally left it out when I trimmed down the example.

Comment: I probably didn't get it? Anyway, why are `null` and `"NaN"` used as example, this happens for integers right, not strings like `NaN` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I did ask it an hour ago and somebody marked it of a duplicate of a question that had NOTHING to do with what I am asking which effectively shut my question down.

Comment: no problem, just thought I'd seen it before :p still like to know what `deliver_response` is ... and also if you know exactly what the PHP code is actually receiving from the "external api"

Comment: @JaromandaX The response from the api is this: {\"Success\":false,\"ErrorMessage\":\"An unhandled exception has occurred and been logged.\"} and I'm positive that it is because I'm sending strings instead of ints

Comment: can you add the function `deliver_response` to your question for completeness?

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood the question

Comment: @RamRaider I added the response I get from the api. is that what your asking? I am not great with php and I don't 100% know what deliver_response is.

Comment: `"data": { json: { data } }` looks wrong @ should that not simply be `"data": { json:data }`?

Comment: Why are you not defining `content-type` in your ajax request? Maybe this is messing with the data you sent.

Comment: `deliver_response` is a php function - presumably written by you ?

Comment: @RamRaider - in modern browsers, that would be the same as `"data": { json: { data : data }}` - agree it looks unintended

Comment: whichever way - it looks wrong

Comment: @RamRaider I don't think it is wrong because it causes the data to go to the server structured they way it is supposed to. I changed it to your suggestion and the data was no longer structured properly

Comment: @ParantapParashar define content-type causes error stating the content-type is not allowed in pre-flight request.

Comment: `"crossDomain": true,` - why? your request is not cross domain to the PHP

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is. The site is hosted on Hubspot which doesn't allow for server side scripting so my proxy is hosted on my company staging server and the api is hosted with a third party company.

Comment: @JaromandaX that is exactly what I need to be sending to the server so I am glad it is doing what I need it to be doing.

Comment: anyway, without setting a datatype for the request, your POST data looks like `json[data][Units][0][InsuranceID]NaN` when `sendinsid` is null, or `json[data][Units][0][InsuranceID]1` if it's a number (1 in this example)

Comment: @JSum - I was wrong, I **assumed** you set the data type to JSON - you didn't, so you get the above

Comment: @JaromandaX Why would it return from the script as Json ony with strings instead of ints? also I have updated my code with the data-type and the issue is the same.

Comment: there is no JSON in your POST data

Comment: @jSum Could you please define the points or places in your code where you print your data to print given output?Because the place where your php script generates the output for ajax request is unclear.

Comment: @ParantapParashar I am returing $data from the wssLocationReserve function to my ajax call for testing purposes (finished project would return $result). I am console.logging $data (d2) in my javascript inside the .done function of the ajax call.

Comment: so, to clarify ... the website is on `server A`, the ajax request is to PHP on `server B` which makes the request on `server C` ... the issue is that `server B` is not getting the data you expect from `server A`

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab to see exactly what the browser is sending in the POST request, you will see that the browser is a) NOT sending JSON, and b) sending NaN instead of null

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes to your server break down. I think I found the same issue in the post but the answers don't really give me an idea of how to break the data apart in php. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745627/how-to-send-int-type-parameters-using-jquery

Comment: @JSum try `"data": { json: JSON.stringify({ data }) }`.